# Divide authorship string into authors

Tags: python, parsing, tokenize

I am trying to devise a smart way to divide a string of authors, the problem is that the string uses commas not only for the division between authors, but also for the division between their first and last names. So an example would be:

```
"LastName1, F.N., LastName2, S.N, Lastname3, T."
```

I could use some tokenize function to divide the string by tokens and then join them afterwards, but I don't think this is robust:

```
def tokenize(str, token=','):
  return [x for x in re.split(r'\s*%s\s*' % token,str) if x]

def grouper(iterable, n, fillvalue=None):
    "Collect data into fixed-length chunks or blocks"
    # grouper('ABCDEFG', 3, 'x') --> ABC DEF Gxx"
    args = [iter(iterable)] * n
    return itertools.zip_longest(*args, fillvalue=fillvalue)

auth = "LastName1, F.N., LastName2, S.N, Lastname3, T."
tmp1 = tokenize(auth)
tmp2 = grouper(tmp1, 2)
print(["{} {}".format(*i) for i in tmp2])
```

Running this code returns:

```
['LastName1 F.N.', 'LastName2 S.N', 'Lastname3 T.']
```

Is there a better (more robust) way to do this?

Answer (score 0):

Here is a real simple tokenizer, written specifically for commas, (so it is clear what it is doing):

```
def tokenize(str):
    return re.findall(r'([^,]*,[^,]*),?', str)
```

It looks for string, comma, string, with optional tailing comma, returning all matches.

Comment: My experience is that regular expressions are the least robust approach. Every time I wrote a `re` to do something it failed due to a special case.

Answer (score 0):

Does this do what you want?

```
>>> auth = 'LastName1, F.N., LastName2, S.N, Lastname3, T.'
>>> names = tuple(map(str.strip, auth.split(',')))
>>> assert not len(names) & 1, 'names must come in pairs'
>>> data = [names[offset:offset+2][::-1] for offset in range(0, len(names), 2)]
>>> print(data)
[('F.N.', 'LastName1'), ('S.N', 'LastName2'), ('T.', 'Lastname3')]
```

It provides a list with pairs of first and last names.

**EDIT:**

Here is a correction based on your comment.

```
>>> auth = 'LastName1, F.N., LastName2, S.N, Lastname3, T.'
>>> names = tuple(map(str.strip, auth.split(',')))
>>> assert not len(names) & 1, 'names must come in pairs'
>>> data = [' '.join(names[index:index+2]) for index in range(0, len(names), 2)]
>>> print(data)
['LastName1 F.N.', 'LastName2 S.N', 'Lastname3 T.']
```

The output appears to be exactly the same now as what you wanted.

Comment: Not really, I want the output I put in the post.

Comment: Yes, that's it. But why is this your solution better than the one in the post? Could you please comment on that?

Comment: @aaragon Based on your comment to [swstephe](http://stackoverflow.com/users/2626001/swstephe), one way in which it is better is that regular expressions are avoided. Another is that it is simple while taking less space. You only needs lines 2 and 4 to arrive at an answer.

Comment: Is it faster? Could you please explain in the answer what the data line does?